# Unable to unset the LOCK password Android 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, password

I have already read [this Google help page](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819522?hl=en-GB) as well as [Unable to disable password on Android screen lock](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/123302/16575) and several other links that explain how to a screen lock password/pin.

I am using Android 4.4.4 with developer options enabled and I cannot remove the password on my phone or change it to a PIN or change to a different password.

When I click on Settings -> (Connections, Device, Controls, General) -> I click General -> Security -> I only see Encryption, Find My Mobile, SIM card lock, Passwords (make password visible), Device Administrators (I made sure than none of them were checked), Security update service, Credential storage.

There is no option to change my password or to use a PIN. Can someone tell me how I can use say a 4 digit pin instead of a password? It is a real pain when I have to type a big password with letters and digits everytime I have to make a call.

Comment: You might look in the wrong place. Check *Settings › Lock Screen* to switch the *method* of unlock to use (PIN/pattern/password/swipe are considered "methods to unlock your screen").

Comment: What I am saying is that under settings there is no lock screen

Comment: I can't see your settings page from here. Maybe you include a screenshot from the first page – or list the entries found at top level? It's usually the first item after the network stuff.